# Spec for a Terminal Services box?

Tags: windows-server-2003, resources, specifications

Currently, we have a test TS machine at work, which has a dual core Pentium 4 3GHz CPU, and 1.5GB of RAM, running 32bit server2003 (I didn't built it, not my choices). My boss wants to get this using Terminal Services, for about 50 light users (browsing the web, word, nothing to heavy). Considering this gives each user 30MB of RAM (assuming none for the OS), this clearly isn't going to work. What sort of spec would you recommend for a machine like this? What's a reasonable amount of RAM per user? Is CPU going to be a bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run an ASP for a specific application based on TS/Citrix.  a 50-user server for me is a 2000 Server with 4 GB RAM and dual Xeon 2.8 GHz CPUs.

Change to 2000 Server with 4 GB RAM and dual dual-core AMD 2.2 GHz CPUs and I get 75 users.

Change to 2003 Server with 16 GB RAM and dual quad-core 2.2 Xeons and I get 140 users.